# Do you have to have python installed on your mac to run Platypus apps?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, platypus

I have discovered Platypus yesterday. Nonetheless, after transforming a few of my script into apps using platypus, I decided to test them out on another Mac little did I know, each time I would run the app it would reveal the following error:

```
Missing Interpreter
This application cannot run because the interpreter ... does not exist
```

At this point, I'm very confident that the error occurs because platypus can't find python on my device.

Therefore Is it possible to create a .app from a python script and running it on devices without python? if not is there another tool with such a feature? (also please note that I'm using python3)

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Check out Py2App - http://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @Chris Thanks for your reply, what is the main advantage of Py2App? (I was planning on using it yesterday, but I found platypus way easier)

Comment: The sole purpose of Py2App is to make Python scripts into MacOS app files that can run like any other Mac app. It’s not that hard to use once you have it set up. I’ve never used Platypus actually, so I cannot compare. Does it have a similar feature?

Comment: @Chris Definitely try Platypus (https://sveinbjorn.org/platypus) it requires literally nothing just the script itself  and it is a .app program so you don't have to `pip install` anything.

Comment: @Chris Do you know it with Py2App the mac that will run the app has to have python and all the packages preinstalled? or you could literally run the app on a mac that never seen Python in its life?

Comment: Yes as far as I know, once you build the app for deployment, it will run on any other Mac. Thanks for the Platypus link - I’ll check it out!

Comment: Mac OSX has shipped with Python for years. But it may only have Python 2. If you do install a more modern version _do not_ attempt to remove the system Python or Bad Things will happen.

Comment: @PM2Ring thank you for your reply, I'm well aware of Python being shipped with all mac, the problem is that my script is in Python 3 not 2 so not everyone is running this version.

Comment: Ok, I was just responding to "a mac that never seen Python in its life".

Comment: While I can’t check it right now, I’m pretty confident that a Py2App app will even run on a Mac without python - everything it needs is included in the bundle.